# `import *` - is it acceptable when importing from a helper file?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on a Python project in which I have a main file `main.py` and a file `helper.py` which contains several functions and classes that are used in `main.py`.

Is it a poor practice to use `from helper import *` in this case? In particular, I am 100% sure that there will be no name conflicts, but in general it seems that avoiding `import *` is considered a best practice.

Comment: this boils down to preferences ... generally avoid star imports(its not clear all the time where something came from  or which actual parts are used when you do this)... but sometimes they might be ok ...

Comment: This question is purely opinion based and not fit for this site. You said it yourself: *"In particular, I am 100% sure that there will be no name conflicts"* - then why not use the `*` import? It exists for a reason. Same as conventions and practices do, but it's up to us to use judgement. Personally I do use `*` imports on small script libraries I use as utilities where the code is cleaner without module prefixes everywhere and I know there are no conflicts as I am the only maintainer I find it fine... As I said this question already presents 3 different opinions and is off-topic

Comment: @Tomerikoo This question is not purely opinion based. It is a question about best practices in the Python community to ensure that there is consistent and legible code across projects. That having been said, as others have mentioned a star import renders it difficult to tell which library a function came from if multiple star imports are used.

Comment: You seem to be aware that doing `import *` is considered bad practice. You're asking if ***in your specific case*** it *would be ok*. That is completely opinion based as is evident by this very question

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, bad practice *in general*. There are exceptions to every rule, and I was inquiring about whether or not this scenario would be one of the exceptions. Asking about best practices and a specific scenario in which following "best practices" may not actually be best practices is not at all an opinion. I am trying to ensure that my code is in good shape to be shared with the community, I don't think we should discourage that, especially when I have clearly considered what is right on my own before asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a lot of functions from helper, then * won't be of much difference. Maybe just import the helper and then use helper.somemethod

Comment: Thanks for the input! Got it - I wanted to avoid having to type out `helper.` every time but maybe that is the best way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your claim *"If you use a lot of functions from helper, then * won't be of much difference"*... I would say that if anything the opposite is true. If you use a lot of functions from helper, then it would be easier ***not*** needing to precede all of them with `helper.`...

Comment: * won't be of much difference (compared to explicitly importing 8 out of 10 methods for example)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I ended up listing out the imports as such:

```
from helpers import (
  function1,
  function2,
  ...
  functionN
)
```

Where the functions/classes are sorted alphabetically